# Create new string from existing one using regex in Postgresql

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql

I am using postgresql as database system (v 9.6.5). I have a table T with a column `code`. I want to add a new column `sorting_code`. `sorting_code` is an another way to write the `code`.

`code` is a combination of (in this order) characters, numbers and +, e.g `12e+`, `234rr++` or `9999mo` are examples of codes. In regex, my code is something like:

`[0-9]+[a-z]*\+*`
(only numbers are required)

What I want to do for my column `sorting_code` is to transform my `code` like that:

12e+ => **000**12**0000**e**0000**+

234rr++ => **00**234**000**rr**000**++

9999mo => **0**9999**000**mo**00000**

In other words, each part (characters, numbers and +) must be exactly 5 characters long. Missing characters being replaced by 0.

I have already a lot of rows in my table T with code. What could be my psql request to create my new column `sorting_code`?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the Regular expression implementation of `substring` along with `lpad` could get you there:

```
select
  val,
  lpad (coalesce (substring (val, '\d+'), ''), 5, '0') ||
  lpad (coalesce (substring (val, '[A-Za-z]+'), ''), 5, '0') ||
  lpad (coalesce (substring (val, '\++'), ''), 5, '0') as sorting_code
from t
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do it which such bicycle:

```
t=# with s(v) as (values('12e+'),('234rr++'),('9999mo'))
, m as (select regexp_matches(v,'[a-z]{1,}','g') l,v,e,p , max(p) over(partition by v)
from s, regexp_split_to_table(v,'[a-z]') with ordinality o (e,p)
)
select lpad(m.e,5,'0')||lpad(m.l[1],5,'0')||lpad(n.e,5,'0') from m join m n on m.v = n.v and m.p=1 and n.p = n.max;
    ?column?
-----------------
 000120000e0000+
 00234000rr000++
 09999000mo00000
(3 rows)
```